# Does an if re match & group capture in the same line?

Tags: python, python-re

Is there a way in Python to do an if re match & group capture in the same line?

In PERL I would do it like this:

```
my $line = "abcdef";

if ($line =~ m/ab(.*)ef/) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

output:

```
badger@pi0: scripts $ ./match.py
cd
```

but the closest way I can find in Python is like this:

```
import re

line = 'abcdef'

if re.search('ab.*ef', line):
    match = re.findall('ab(.*)ef', line)
    print(match[0])
```

output:

```
badger@pi0: scripts $ ./match.pl
cd
```

which would seem to have to do the match twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `search`.  You don't need it.

```
matches = re.findall('ab(.*)ef', line)
print(matches)
```

Or if you're only interested in the first match, remove the `findall`:

```
match = re.search('ab(.*)ef', line)
if match:
    print(match.group(1)) # 0 is whole string, 1 is first capture
```

Comment: perfect, thank you, that's exactly what I was after.  :)